# Execute a custom shell script before the aegir verify

Tags: aegir

Every actions in aegir trigger a verify.

I would like to automatically execute a shell script before that verify (rsync of plateforms).

How could I proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a drush_hook_pre_COMMAND() hook in drush to run any code you'd like.

See the docs page for more details: https://docs.aegirproject.org/extend/altering-behaviours/#running-extra-code-after-a-task

Comment: This is a post_verify command : drush_server_data_post_provision_verify() { 
  }. is there a pre-verify ? or what is the command just before verify to do a post_{thatCommand} ?

Comment: Drush automatically offers a ton of these hooks ... where the example says 'post' you can enter 'pre'.  See [the example module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/hosting/blob/7.x-3.x/example/server_data/drush/server_data.drush.inc) for more inspiration. 'server_data' would be the name of your drupal module in this case.